# Git -- merge master with branch and create new file from master that was renamed

Tags: git, github

I'm trying merge in the master branch to my own branch, using 
`git merge master`
after doing
`git checkout mybranch`.

I renamed a file in my branch from `something.py` to `something-old.py`.

Everything seems all good after I merge, but the `something.py` file does not show up in `mybranch`.  Is there an easy way to get the file (or if it was 100s of files I renamed, etc) back to match the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout master something.py` will pull file something.py from master into your current working copy